# How do I find the Cache Block Address when I am given Memory Block Address and the Number of Blocks and they type of Associate Cache?

Tags: cpu-architecture

So I have been given the following:

1. Memory Block Address as 462 (in decimals)
2. Direct Mapped Cache
3. 2<sup>2</sup> Blocks

The question is to find the Cache Block Address.

My teacher gave the equation: Cache Block Address = Memory Block Address % No. of Blocks

When I use this equation I get Cache Block Address = 462%4 = 2

But the answer given is 231 which I am assuming is obtained by 462/log<sub>2</sub>(4)

Can someone help me with this. I am a bit confused

Comment: 2² would be an extremely small number for the count of blocks — that is more likely the block size, but who knows?

Comment: Your teacher will have all the details of the question they assigned, so they'll be able to explain better than we can.  Your `%` formula for "cache block address" is the index, which cache line within the cache it uses.  If your cache only has 4 lines, the possible indexes are 0..3, like you calculated.  Maybe they actually want you to calculate the tag, the part of the address that doesn't include the index bits.  (Or the offset-within-line bits, but those are already factored out by working in "blocks", not bytes).